# Como desabilitar um QLineEdit no Pyqt?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt-5

Como faço para desabilitar um `QLineEdit` no Pyqt5?

Exemplo:

```python
  inputUserName = QLineEdit(self)
```

Gostaria de deixá-lo desabilitado, igual no `Html`, quando usamos o atributo `disabled`. É possível?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar o método [**`setDisabled`**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setDisabled) de **`QWidget`**. `QLineEdit` herda desta classe.

```python
inputUserName.setDisabled(True)
```

Answer (score 4):

Complementando a resposta do [LINQ](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/18246/):

Também pode usar o método `setEnabled` ("enabled" = "habilitado"):

```python
inputUserName.setEnabled(False)  #desabilita o controle

inputUserName.setEnabled(True)   #habilita o controle
```

Obviamente o booleano funciona no sentido inverso do `setDisabled`.